# MS Word ActiveX Textbox Spell Check

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a MS Word form for a client where they want the ability to count the number of words, check spelling, have a character limit, and have the rest of the form locked down so that the end user cannot change anything they are not supposed to.  I have attempted to convince them that word count and character limit are redundant if we have proper instructions, however, this is what they want.  They also want the form to be able to "work" even if the user does not enable macros, meaning, they want it locked and a character limit first and foremost.

I know that if we just rich text content controls and put the form into a group spell check and word count word while also "locking" the remainder of the form, except user content controls do not allow for character limits and using legacy/activex controls in a grouped form locks those controls as well.

So, for now, I have settled on using the ActiveX Textbox (this is negotiable if I have a reason to use the legacy textbox) and have achieved the minimum "workability" (if that's even a word).  The only way I have figured out to check the spelling is below:

```
Sub chkSpelling()

Activedocument.Tables(1).Rows(26).Cells(1).Range.Text = txtRole.Text
Activedocument.Tables(1).Rows(26).Cells(1).Range.checkSpelling
txtRole.Text = Activedocument.Tables(1).Rows(26).Cells(1).Range.Text

'... so on and so forth throughout each text box

End Sub
```

The issue is that this is not good enough for my standards.  Printing the text of each textbox (up to 1700 characters) at the bottom of the screen each time I need to check the Spelling is unacceptable.  Does anyone else have any ideas?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer with help from @bibadia

```
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = Documents.Add(, , wdNewBlankDocument, False)

doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = txtRole.Text
doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.CheckSpelling
txtRole.Text = Replace(doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text, Chr(13), "")
```

Comment: Does this even have to be done in Word?

Comment: yes, unfortunately, it does.

Comment: Pretty nasty situation, then. I haven't checked feasibility, but could you createobject a new word instance with .visible = false, copy the text into a document in there, and spell check that?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I just hope it doesn't become visible once it finds a misspelled word.  Thank you

Comment: I've put that up as an Answer. I was also unsure about whether the relevant dialogs would work with an invisible document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `CreateObject` to create a new word instance
2. Ensure `.Visible = False` (I think that is the default)
3. Create a new document in that instance.
4. Copy the text to be checked into that
5. Spell check.
6. Remove the document and the Word instance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then,

```
I need to check the Spelling is unacceptable. Does anyone else have any ideas?
```

If text boxes are named with numbers, you might be able to use loop, and save your coding lines with time.

```
want the form to be able to "work" even if the user does not enable macros
```

If user did not enable macros, he would not be able to see form (is it User Form, you want to say) and no background macro code would run. (Tested on Ms-Excel 2007), ultimately failing all.

```
regarding text box control on user form
```

yes that can be set to character limit from properties menu, and spell check can be done using your method.

```
Set range2 = Documents("MyDocument.doc").Sections(2).Range
range2.CheckSpelling IgnoreUpperCase:=False, _
    CustomDictionary:="MyWork.Dic", _
    CustomDictionary2:="MyTechnical.Dic"
```

Comment: by form I didn't mean user form, I meant data collection form.  Can't really think of a better way to describe it.  I go to developer --> restrict editing --> Filling In Forms to lock the document down and only allow editing where there are text boxes.